# Object pointer value as key into dictionary

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, reference

I want to use the object's reference value as a key into a dictionary, as opposed to a copy of value of the object. So, I essentially want to store an object associated with a particular instance of another object in a dictionary and retrieve that value later.

Is this possible? Is it completely against the idea of NSDictionary? I can tell that I am probably approaching this the wrong way because the dictionary wants me to implement NSCopying on the object itself, which doesn't really make sense in terms of what I'm doing. I can see that what I should really be doing is wrapping the pointer value, but that seems a little mad.

Advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can use `[NSValue valueWithPointer:object]`.

Answer (score 2):

[NSMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has been designed to only deal with Objective-C object instances. For example, when you call `setObject:forKey:` method calls `copyWithZone:` on the key and `retain` on the value.

If you want to have a dictionary structure and to be able to deal with arbitrary key and value, then you can go with [CFMutableDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFMutableDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html). You can describe precisely what is done with key and values; it is flexible enough to deal with arbitrary pointer or event `char *` strings.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me

```
aDictionary[@((intptr_t)object)] = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the address in memory of myObejct as a key in myDictionary

```
NSString *myObject_addressInMemory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%p", myObject];

myDictionary[myObject_addressInMemory] = someValue;
```