# Pointers to NSMutableDictionary objects

Tags: objective-c, pointers, key, nsmutabledictionary

I have a following sample code:

```
NSNumber * number1 = @231;
NSNumber * number2 = @322;
NSLog(@"number1: %@", number1);
NSLog(@"number2: %@", number2);
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[dict setObject:number1 forKey:@"number"];
NSNumber * outNumber = [dict objectForKey:@"number"];
NSLog(@"outNumber: %@",outNumber);
[dict setObject:number2 forKey:@"number"];
NSLog(@"outNumber: %@",outNumber);
```

After updating the value under "number" key in the dictionary the outNumber object still points to the previous value (231).

Is there a way in Objective-C to make it so that the outNumber object always points to the current value under "number" key in dictionary ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708168/object-pointer-value-as-key-into-dictionary

Comment: last line, you have print outNumber which is set before the number2. so its always give you number1 output

Comment: print last line like this way.. `NSLog(@"outNumber: %@",[dict objectForKey:@"number"]);`

Comment: Of course I can do that but that's not the point. I would like the value that's pointed to by outNumber to always correspond to the current value of objectForKey: @"number" without having to reassign it to the variable outNumber.

Answer (score 0):

You have didn't print updated dictionary so, add below 2 line in your end of code:

```
NSNumber * outNumber2 = [dict objectForKey:@"number"];
NSLog(@"outNumber: %@",outNumber2);
```

Hope will helpful to you!!